# bootstrap new theme not working in drupal with mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I have developed a theme for drupal 7 based on bootstrap 3. It is working fine for desktop browsers. When re size the window also it is showing nicely which should be in the way of mobile browser. But if I see it in a real device none of the mobile features are working which is provided by the bootstrap. The url is http://www.iplaza.selikta.com

Can anyone please give me suggestions. I really appreciate.

Comment: Your url es incorrect, could you correct it?

Comment: Sorry about the url. The correct one is www.iplaza.selikta.com

Comment: Works as expected on a Nexus 4

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have this line in the `<head>` section of your pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Just hit this issue on a Bootstrap theme I inherited where this was commented out in the html.tpl.php file within the Bootstrap theme. Uncommenting this line solved the problem.